# TensorFlow Keras: The `validate_indices` argument has no effect. Indices are always validated on CPU and never validated on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

It was yesterday and I was training the model. Everything looked good.
Today 27/05/2021 I receive this warning:

*WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:5049: calling gather (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with validate_indices is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
The `validate_indices` argument has no effect. Indices are always validated on CPU and never validated on GPU.*

I'm running my CNN on GoogleColab pro.

**Does someone know what to do to fix it?** I didn't change anything, and I thought that Tensorflow-Keras should handle the CPU-GPU computations.

After, the normal flow of model.fit:

Epoch 1/200

216/216 - 18s - loss: ...

Epoch 2/200

216/216 - 2s - loss: ...

Comment: You can ignore this warning message, since it is a deprecated message.They will be removed in a future version. Deprecated, does nothing. Indices are always validated on CPU, never validated on GPU means - On CPU, if an out of bound index is found, an error is raised. On GPU, if an out of bound index is found, a 0 is stored in the corresponding output value. For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather). Thanks!